# ¿Por qué falla el código usando la estructura condicional if pero usando la estructura de control switch no falla?

Tags: java, condiciones

El programa consiste en una cuenta bancaria. el cual muestro a continuación:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static boolean changeBalance(Account account, Operation operation, Long sum) {
       
        if (operation == Operation.DEPOSIT) {
            account.balance += sum;
            return true;

        } else if (operation == Operation.WITHDRAW) {
              if (account.balance < sum) {
                  System.out.println("Not enough money to withdraw.");
                  return false;
            } else {
                  account.balance -= sum;
                  return true;
            }
        }
    }
 //comento el switch el cual si funciona correctamente

/* switch (operation) {
        case DEPOSIT:
            account.balance += sum;
            return true;
        case WITHDRAW:
            if (account.balance < sum) {
                System.out.println("Not enough money to withdraw.");
                return false;
            } else {
                account.balance -= sum;
                return true;
            }
        default:
            return false;
    }
}*/

    enum Operation {
 
        DEPOSIT,
   
        WITHDRAW
    }

    static class Account {

        private String code;
        private Long balance;

        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public Long getBalance() {
            return balance;
        }

        public void setBalance(Long balance) {
            this.balance = balance;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");

        Account account = new Account();
        account.setBalance(Long.parseLong(parts[0]));

        Operation operation = Operation.valueOf(parts[1]);

        Long sum = Long.parseLong(parts[2]);

        if (changeBalance(account, operation, sum)) {
            System.out.println(account.getBalance());
        }
}
}
```

Este programa me arroja un error usando el if:

> "missing return statement"

En cambio cuando utilizo en lugar del if el switch (el cual coloque en este ejemplo como un comentario) el programa no arroja ningún error y funciona correctamente, pero utilice las mismas instrucciones tanto para uno como para el otro. no entiendo cual es la diferencia o como se puede solucionar este error usando el if.

Comment: A mi opinión debes tener un solo return afuera del switch, el error te marca porque tu función debe retornar un `boolean` y no lo encuentra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fácil, tu función siempre tiene que retornar un valor booleano en su ejecución:

```
 switch (operation) {
    case DEPOSIT:
        account.balance += sum;
        return true;
    case WITHDRAW:
        if (account.balance < sum) {
            System.out.println("Not enough money to withdraw.");
            return false;
        } else {
            account.balance -= sum;
            return true;
        }
    default:
        return false;
}
```

tanto en el caso "Deposit" o "WITHDRAW" devuelve un boolean en caso que no sea ni "Deposit" , ni "WITHDRAW" devuelve false ahora si miras tu condiconal if te vas a dar cuenta que :

```
 if (operation == Operation.DEPOSIT) {
        account.balance += sum;
        return true;

    } else if (operation == Operation.WITHDRAW) {
          if (account.balance < sum) {
              System.out.println("Not enough money to withdraw.");
              return false;
        } else {
              account.balance -= sum;
              return true;
        }
    }
```

falta un caso para que tenga el mismo comportamiento que el switch, que es el caso ni DEPOSIT ni WITHDRAW :

```
 if (operation == Operation.DEPOSIT) {
        account.balance += sum;
        return true;

    } else if (operation == Operation.WITHDRAW) {
          if (account.balance < sum) {
              System.out.println("Not enough money to withdraw.");
              return false;
        } else {
              account.balance -= sum;
              return true;
        }
    }
```

solo debes agregar un return al final del metodo :

```
public static boolean changeBalance(Account account, Operation operation, Long sum) {
   
    if (operation == Operation.DEPOSIT) {
        account.balance += sum;
        return true;

    } else if (operation == Operation.WITHDRAW) {
          if (account.balance < sum) {
              System.out.println("Not enough money to withdraw.");
              return false;
        } else {
              account.balance -= sum;
              return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Genial, Gracias, esto ha solucionado mi problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Ya la respuesta fue dada por @altoqueperro, pero me gustaría proponer un enfoque con un solo return.

```
public static boolean changeBalance(Account account, Operation operation, Long sum) {
    
    //Declarar una variable resultado
    boolean resultado = false;

    if (operation == Operation.DEPOSIT) {
        account.balance += sum;
        resultado = true;

    } else if (operation == Operation.WITHDRAW) {
        if (account.balance < sum) {
              System.out.println("Not enough money to withdraw.");
              // aquí no hace falta asignar el resultado porque ya es false
        } else {
              account.balance -= sum;
              resultado = true;
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```